# Join function not working

Tags: perl, join

Below script break the sequence at every 'E' and subsequently an 'E' is added on to each fragment. But I'm not getting 'E' attached to my last element, Why?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE';
my @a = split /E(?!P)/, $s;

my $result = join "E,", @a; 
my @final  = split /,/, $result;
print "@final\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation of `split`:

> By default, empty leading fields are preserved, and empty trailing ones are deleted.

Comment: is there any way to include 'E' in last element by modifying above code?

Comment: @prashant `my $result = join ("E,", @a) . 'E';`

Comment: @prashant: `my $result = join 'E', @a, '';`

Answer (score 2):

A `join` joins its first argument **between** successive elements.  If you want to add the final "E", you could simply do:

```
$s = 'ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE';
@a = split(/E(?!P)/, $s);
print join ("E ", @a), "E\n";
```